# "Cannot read property 'utils' of undefined" on web3.utils

Tags: web3js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

This is my code:

```
import {web3} from "hardhat"


const OWNER_ROLE = web3.utils.keccak256("OWNER_ROLE");
```

This is the error in my terminal:

```
const OWNER_ROLE = web3.utils.keccak256("OWNER_ROLE");
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'utils' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are importing from the correct library?

I think it should be this instead:

```
import web3 from "web3"
```